# trouble using cgal and cmake

Tags: cmake, cgal

I have to do a project using CMake and the CGAL geometry library but, regardless having tried everything I can find online, I still can't figure out how to configure my project in CMake. I have installed all the libraries CGAL depends on and qt5 but CMake keeps giving me errors when I try to configure and generate. I am almost a beginner so any kind of help would be very useful. I am using windows 10 and visual studio 2019. Following are the errors it's giving me.

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package): By not providing "FindCGAL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL" with any of the following names:

CGALConfig.cmake
cgal-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "CGAL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "CGAL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "CGAL" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.22.0-rc2")

project("TesiLaurea")

find_package(CGAL)

add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" "Main.cpp")

target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" CGAL::CGAL)
```

Comment: Please, add the CMakeLists.txt and the error messages to the question. Otherwise it's hard to guess what went wrong from your description.

Comment: hope this is enough I honestly have no idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try to follow the suggestions in the error message about CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or CGAL_DIR?

Comment: I have tried setting CGAL_DIR to the directory which contains CGALConfig.cmake and it gives me even more errors. I cannot post them in this answer since Stack Overflow doesn't give me enough characters.

Comment: update: it seems that most of the errors are now about CMake not finding GMP and MFPR libraries. They are both installed via vcpkg automatically when you install CGAL  so I don't know why it keeps telling me they can't be found. (Could NOT find GMP (missing: GMP_LIBRARIES)is the exact error message).

Comment: It seems you are using VCPKG to build and install CGAL or  its dependencies so you need to add the toolchain file to your cmake command, for instance `cmake -B <builddir> -S <sourcedir> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<pathtovcpkg>/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64`  for a 64bit build. If you have installed CGAL 32bit replace `-A x64` with `-A Win32`.

Comment: @vre thank you very much your suggestion solved all the problems I had encountered. Neither on the CGAL official site or in the CMake error's console or anywhere on the internet was it specified to do so. Once again thank you from the bottom of my heart.